# Wordpress Docker Compose Nginx block y client CSS and JS files on EC2

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have developed a WordPress website that works perfectly fine on my local machine. However, when I deploy it on an EC2 instance, I encounter the following error:

> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:717     GET http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/rs6.css?ver=6.5.14 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:721     GET http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/quarter-addon/assets/js/quarter-addon.js?ver=6.2.2 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:722     GET http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/swv/js/index.js?ver=5.8 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:726     GET http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/index.js?ver=5.8 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:727     GET http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/rbtools.min.js?ver=6.5.14 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
> inmopage.duckdns.org/:728

All the CSS and JavaScript files are being blocked by the client. Here are some additional details about my setup:

I am using an EC2 instance to host my WordPress website.
The instance is running the Nginx web server as a reverse proxy, which forwards requests to a PHP-FPM container running WordPress.
I have opened the necessary ports (80 and 443) in the security group associated with the EC2 instance.
I have set the correct DNS record for the domain and can access the website without any issues.
When I inspect the network requests in the browser's developer console, I can see that all the CSS and JavaScript files are being blocked by the client with the error ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT.
I have tried clearing the browser cache and disabling any ad-blocking extensions, but the issue persists.

This are my configurations

```
#docker compose.ym;
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Web2023##
      MYSQL_DATABASE: inmopage
      MYSQL_USER: inmopageuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: web2023
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./wordpress_config/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: inmopageuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: web2023
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: inmopage
    expose:
      - 9000

  nginx:
      depends_on:
        - wordpress
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443

volumes:
  db_data: {}
    


#NGINX dockerfile
# Dockerfile NGINX
FROM nginx:latest


# Eliminar el archivo de configuración predeterminado de Nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Agregar nuestro archivo de configuración de Nginx
COPY ./server/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Create log directory and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx && \
    touch /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    touch /var/log/nginx/error.log && \
    chmod -R 777 /var/log/nginx



#Nginx server config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nginx;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}





# Dockerfile WORDPRESS
FROM wordpress:5-fpm

COPY ./wordpress_config/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

RUN echo "upload_max_filesize = 64M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/upload_large_images.ini \
    && echo "post_max_size = 64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/upload_large_images.ini


#Wordpress entrypoint
#!/bin/bash
set -e


chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
docker-php-entrypoint "$@"

# Start php-fpm in the background
php-fpm &

# Keep script in the foreground
tail -f /dev/null

# Start php-fpm in the background and redirect logs to stdout and stderr
php-fpm > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 &

# Keep script in the foreground
tail -f /dev/null
```